# How to add videos to index page?

Tags: wordpress, video, indexing

I need to add videos to my single page Wordpress website. I've been looking at some plugins for this but all of these only allow adding videos to posts or pages. Since I'm only using the index.php I don't know how to add a video there.. And I would prefer not to use embedded videos from Youtube, Vimeo etc.

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

@andreas Could you please explain better what you are trying to achieve?

if is only a video in your template you can use something like this..
`<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.mydomain.com/myvideo.mov"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.mydomain.com/myvideo.mov" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>`